# scattering instances in Blender

Tags: particles, hair, instances

Let's say, I want to populate a parking lot with cars. Coming from Modo, I'd use replicators:
-create an array of polygons, one for each parking space
-create a group of cars
-add a replicator item, that would place one car on every polygon and use the 
   polygon's rotation to place the replica
-I could do a random rotation in 180 degree increments, to get some randomness
-I could also rotate polygons manually for more control
-A percentage slider and seed value allowed me to control how full the parking 
   lot was

Is there a way to do something similar in blender? I've come quite close with the hair system, but I can't figure out how to precisely control the Z rotation of individual hairs

Any pointers will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might have better luck with [dupligroups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupligroup.html) if you want manual control. If you use duplifaces you can control orientation, and iirc there is a tool to randomize face orientation

Comment: cool! this works nicely, although I haven't been able to figure out the randomization part just yet. Is there also a way to do this controlled duplication with a group or a hierarchy, so that I don't have to merge the whole model before duplicating it?

Comment: I came close to getting something like that working with groups and mask modifiers, but I realized particles should allow this after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's particle system is.. weird. It's a more little old and probably could do with a refactor. Among other things, [the axis are wrong](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8919/599).

However, that doesn't mean it can't be made to work:

1. Switch to emission particles
2. Enable rotation

   [image]
3. Rotate your emitter polygons so that their surface normals are aligned with the +Y axis of the instance:

   [image]

[image]

Comment: ah, this is cool! thanks! It's quite a shame the X axis gets ignored, but this does make my problem seem at least a bit closer to getting solved. Also... how do you update your particle sim after you exit the edit mode of the source surface? my particles didn't update until I changed their number...

Comment: @ivan Hm, I didn't do anything special.. Are you using blender 2.78? I've uploaded the .blend for you to test.

Comment: thanks, works as expected in your file, I'll have to dissect my old file... if I can find it, to find the culprit.